# Filling for Stuffed Chicken Breast

Tags: chicken, chicken-breast

I was wondering what taste good as a filling for chicken breast. I want to make kind of chicken breast pockets by almost cutting through the chicken breast but keeping both sides still together to fill. Then I will fill it and close it with some string or tooth picks. That's very much for any suggestions!

Comment: Closing this as it is essentially a recipe poll; there are [at least 215](http://allrecipes.com/Search/Recipes.aspx?WithTerm=stuffed%20chicken%20breast) ways to stuff a chicken breast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few classics:

Chicken Cordon Blue - Ham and swiss

Chicken Kiev - tarragon, garlic, parsley, butter, etc.

You can use spinach and cream cheese, spinach and bacon, spinach and ricotta.  Mushrooms with different cheeses, there are a ton of different things.

Try this:

google.com

and search:

different types of stuffed chicken breast

Answer (score 1):

Just the other day, I did this and threw them on the grill.

I filled mine with Boursin Cheese, and served them with baked potatos.

Comment: Sounds very good!! :)

Answer (score 0):

- Spinach and mozzarella topped with tomato sauce
- Goat cheese, bacon, and asparagus